# How to make a unique URL for each user in Django?

Tags: python, django, url

I am making website with Django. I want each user to have their own URL, so if a user with the username "john" registers, the URL will be .../user/john or if a user with the username "tim" registers, the URL will be .../user/tim. I also want that when I log in as "tim" and enter .../user/john in the search, I will see John's page.

This is my urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from webapp.views import welcome_page, register, user_page, settings, timeline

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", welcome_page, name="welcome_page"),
    path("register/",register, name="register" ),
    path("", include("django.contrib.auth.urls"), name="login_logout"),
    path("user/",user_page, name="user_page"),
    path("settings/", settings, name="settings"),
    path("main/", timeline, name="main_timeline"),
]
```

And this is my views.py file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import RegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def welcome_page(response):
    return render(response,"welcome.html")

def register(response):
    error = ""
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("/login")

        else:
            error = form.errors

    form = RegisterForm()
    return render(response, "register/register.html", {"form":form, "error" : error})

@login_required
def user_page(response):
    username = str(User.objects.get(username=response.user.username))
    userphoto = username[0:2]
    return render(response, "user_page.html", {"userphoto": userphoto})

@login_required
def settings(response):
    return render(response, "settings.html")

@login_required
def timeline(response):
    return render(response, "timeline.html")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a URL path that accepts a `username`.

##### urls.py

```
path("user/<str:username>/",user_page, name="user_page"),
```

Now your view accepts the username that is passed as part of the URL.

##### views.py

```
def user_page(response, username):
    # Your view logic goes here..
```

If you want to navigate to other users page then you could pass their username in url like this:

> `{% url 'user_page' username %}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Django's url parameters as the following

```
...
path("user/<username>",user_page, name="user_page"),
...
```

And you intercept the username in your views by passing it as parameter as below

```
@login_required
def user_page(response, username):
    ...
```

Kindly check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/) for more details